# how does one grow spiritually thus connecting to Hashem to become a better person and a better Yid?

Tags: theology

I would like to be answered regarding the questions I have on spiritual growth. how does one grow? is it the internal or external factors that enable one to grow? is it possible only to rely on external forces for spiritual growth? if one is in an environment with no positive external forces how much will this impact their growth? thank you i would really appreciate an answer.

Comment: Hi @user24245 welcome to Mi Yodeya! At the moment your question is quite broad, if you could perhaps edit your question to have more focus, you will more likely receive a clearer answer.

Answer (score 0):

how does one grow? - Learn Torah and cherish the *mitzvos*.

is it the internal or external factors that enable one to grow? - Internal.

is it possible only to rely on external forces for spiritual growth? - No.

if one is in an environment with no positive external forces how much will this impact their growth? - It is irrelevant, anything real comes from within yourself.

Comment: i'd like to mention growth is not exclusively internal, you need both external/internal growth to grow

Comment: Rb Dessler says that the purpose of external "growth" is only ever to achieve internal growth.